# Multiple Active Nodes in Server Clusters

Tags: cluster

What does multiple active nodes mean in the context of Server Clusters using MS Windows Server 2003 or later versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you have more than one server actively capable of sharing client load - obviously this depends on how the cluster is setup and what load type it's dealing with but that's the basic idea - two or more computers capable of working on the same tasks.

You can disable an active cluster member, usually temporarily so that you could do some work on it for instance and that would be an inactive cluster member.

Hope this clears up the question - if it doesn't perhaps you could ask again with more detail ok .